# Can I modify the file path of <input type='file'> with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
<form action='http://evil.me' type='post'>
```

If this can happen, files can be automatically uploaded when user browse a website.

```
<a href='www'>ffff</a>

<img src='http://www.runoob.com/try/demo_source/smiley-2.gif'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot set the value of a file `<input>` element with JavaScript.